# Регулярка для php. Обрезать часть url с конца

Tags: php

Есть ссылка https://site.com/ru/folder/product/el/drop

Подскажите какой регуляркой можно обрезать эту ссылку начиная с конца до первого /
то есть что бы получилось:
https://site.com/ru/folder/product/el

Буду очень признателен за помощь.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Для этого не нужны никакие регулярки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = 'https://site.com/ru/folder/product/el/drop';
echo substr($str,0, strrpos($str,"/"));  // strripos  maybe ?
```

---

> суть в том что бы контролировать вложенность, т.е. обрезать до 1 встретившегося с конца слэша, до 2 и т.д.

```
$str = 'https://site.com/ru/folder/product/el/drop';

function getStringFromStartToNSlashFromEnd($str = '', $slashNumber = 1) {
    $slashesCount = 0;
    for ($i = strlen($str) - 1; $i > 0; --$i) {
        if ($str[$i] === '/') {
            $slashesCount++;
        }
        
        if ($slashesCount === $slashNumber) {
            return substr($str, 0, $i);
        }
    }
}

echo getStringFromStartToNSlashFromEnd($str, 2);
```

**NOTE:** доп проверок на всяки пустые строки и что слэшей меньше, чем указано, тут нет

Comment: как-то не очень хорошо получится. если на входе просто `https://site.com` будет )

Comment: ТС написал конкретную строку ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Работает хорошо, но суть в том что бы контролировать вложенность, т.е. обрезать до 1 встретившегося с конца слэша, до 2 и т.д., и именно регулярка, на будущее что бы применять её в разных местах.

Comment: @АлексейСердюк в таком случае проще цикл с конца в начало прогнать, регулярка на вариативность не сработает

Comment: @АлексейСердюк что-то кажется, вы задачу не тему средствами решаете. Откуда вы берете такие ссылки, что их обрезать надо по всякому?

Comment: @АлексейСердюк добавил ответ с циклом.